# Check/Uncheck all checkbox in group Vue.js

Tags: javascript, checkbox, vue.js, vuejs2

I have an Array of checkbox which already divided in to groups and I need to check all child checkbox if parent is checked and uncheck if parent is uncheck and then update all their state in Array. This wayyy over my head since I'm realy new to Vue.

I setup a Codepen [here](https://codepen.io/khanhvdv/pen/NwOmPz), and I can't change Array's structure since it's a JSON response from server.

Js

```
let tree = [
    {
        "text": "AccountController",
        "id": 1,
        "state": {
            "opened": false,
            "selected": true,
            "disabled": false
        },
        "children": [
            {
                "text": "Index",
                "id": 2,
                "state": {
                    "opened": false,
                    "selected": true,
                    "disabled": false
                },
                "children": null
            },
            {
                "text": "Login",
                "id": 3,
                "state": {
                    "opened": false,
                    "selected": true,
                    "disabled": false
                },
                "children": null
            },
      ...
        ]
    },
    {
        "text": "BaseController",
        "id": 19,
        "state": {
            "opened": false,
            "selected": true,
            "disabled": false
        },
        "children": [
            {
                "text": "GetErrorListFromModelState",
                "id": 20,
                "state": {
                    "opened": false,
                    "selected": true,
                    "disabled": false
                },
                "children": null
            },
            {
                "text": "GetErrorFromModelState",
                "id": 21,
                "state": {
                    "opened": false,
                    "selected": true,
                    "disabled": false
                },
                "children": null
            },
      ...
        ]
    }
]
let app = new Vue({
    el : '#clone',
    data : {
        items : tree,

    },
    methods : {
        submitForm() {
            console.log(tree);
        }
    }
});
```

Html

```
<div id="clone">
    <button @click="submitForm">click</button>
    <div class="dd">
        <ol class="dd-list">
            <li v-for="(item, index) in items" 
                v-bind:class="[item.state.opened ? 'dd-item open' : 'dd-item']">
                <div class="dd-handle"
                     @click="item.state.opened = !item.state.opened">
                    <input type="checkbox"
                           :disabled="item.state.disabled" 
                           :name="item.text" 
                           :checked="item.state.selected" 
                           @click="item.state.selected = !item.state.selected">
                    <label :for="item.text">{{item.text}}</label>
                </div>

                <ol v-if="item.children.length != 0" class="dd-list">
                    <li v-for="(children, index) in item.children" 
                        :data-id="children.id" class="dd-item">
                        <div class="dd-handle">
                            <input type="checkbox" 
                                   :name="children.text" 
                                   :checked="children.state.selected" 
                                   :disabled="children.state.disabled" 
                                   @click="children.state.selected = !children.state.selected">
                            <label :for="children.text">{{children.text}}</label>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ol>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can someone enlighten me please. Thank in advance!

Comment: This is easy to do, you just need to add `parent`/ `child` props to the parent and childrens and it would be better next time to post it in jsfiddle.net

Comment: I already setup a Codepen [here](https://codepen.io/khanhvdv/pen/NwOmPz) and I can't change the array structure.

Comment: It's pretty simple even if you can't change the array structure. Just add an event handler like click and pass down an event & index to it `@click='clicked($event ,index)'` and from that index you can iterate through the array and check/uncheck the fields ..

Comment: Also make sure to use jsfiddle next time, it's a lot better than codepen to try/modify some of this stuff

Comment: @samayo I find codepen *far* nicer to work with than jsfiddle.

Comment: @Bert Really? In what way? I find jsfiddle clean and feels like it has more room for you to write. Maybe codepen has some stuff I don't know about

Comment: Snippets are best. :)

Comment: @samayo I can switch the layout based on my needs, I get statistics about views, settings don't take up screen space, default style is better, etc etc. But RoyJ is right too; best option is make it into a SO snippet. To be honest though if someone gives *any* of these options its *fantastic*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the template,

```
<input type="checkbox"
       :disabled="item.state.disabled" 
       :name="item.text" 
       :checked="item.state.selected" 
       @click="item.state.selected = !item.state.selected"
       @change="onChange(item, item.state.selected)">
```

And add the method,

```
methods : {
    submitForm() {
        console.log(tree);
    },
    onChange(item, state){
        for(let child of item.children){
            child.state.selected = state
        }
    }
}
```

Updated [pen](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/BmGBXK?editors=1010).